# IF statement is not valid in this position

Tags: mysql, sql

I have checked/compared SQL statement several times, but it is still not working. I am using WorkBench 6.3 with MySQL. It gives me an error:

> 1064 syntax error: 'IF' is not a valid input at this position.

```
IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM RECORDS WHERE FORMID = 200002016 AND TimeUploaded > '2016-07-17 03:13:39' AND TimeUploaded < '2016-07-17 03:13:39'))
Begin
    SELECT TimeUploaded from RECORDS
End;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use `IF` in an SQL statement. You can only use it in a stored procedure or a function.

You can rewrite your statement like this:

```
SELECT TimeUploaded from RECORDS
WHERE FORMID = 200002016
  AND TimeUploaded > '2016-07-17 03:13:39'
  AND TimeUploaded < '2016-07-17 03:13:39'
```

Comment: thank you, i was stock trying to make "exist" work when what i need is so simple..