# Insert in the IF statement Query in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to run an insert query in the IF statement, As I know the syntax for `if` statement is

`IF(conditon, execute if condition is True, execute if condition is False)`

My question is whether  if it is possible run an insert statement based on the conditions, like

`IF((select count(*) from table where id = x) = 0, insert1, insert2)`

insert1 will be a direct insert like

`insert into table (col1,col2..) values (val1, val2..)`

insert2 will fetch the previous value with the id whose count is not 0 and then do some logic and then insert the query looks like

`insert into table (col1, col2, col3..) select val1,val1+val2,someOperation from table where id = x;`

Comment: pls show us the insert1 and 2 statement

Comment: Please share a complete, reproducible code what you have tried so far, like [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this :

```
IF( select count(*) from Table1 ) is null
begin

    IF( select count(*) from Table1 ) is null
    begin
    --execute if condition is True
    --insert condition
    end

    IF( select count(*) from Table1 ) is not null
    begin
    --execute if condition is False
    --insert condition
    end

end
```

MYSQL example :

```
      IF ((select count(*) from table where id = x)) = 0
        THEN 
         --insert into table (col1,col2..) values (val1, val2..)
        ELSE
             IF ((select count(*) from table where id = x)) != 0
             THEN 
             --insert into table (col1, col2, col3..) select val1,val1+val2,someOperation from table where id = x;
      END IF;
     END IF;
```

Comment: Yeah @Adamszsz, it looks suitable but i wanted to ask if this will work like a query or does it need a stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks for two answers, but your MYSQL example gives "'IF' is not a valid input at this position." and as mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38418622/16331620) this answer 'IF' can't be used in a query statement, i am looking for a solution, which could be executable as a query,

Comment: Hi @aalma better to use stored procedure as it conditional.

Comment: @aalma exacly , you can do it only by procedure  if you want use if conditions , there is no another option.

Comment: Please approve  as an ansewar if i helped you to understand something :) Thank you.