# IF statement in MySQL throwing error - "IF" is not valid at this position, expecting

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to trigger a display of the column SUBMITTER from the Table PBI_COLS in MySQL, if today is a particular date. However, when I write the below code,

```
IF CURRENT_DATE() = '2024-03-14' THEN 
    SELECT SUBMITTER FROM PBI_COLS;
END IF;
```

I get an error at the IF, which says "IF" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ALTER, ANALYZE. What am I doing wrong and how do I correct them?

I tried adding an ELSE but still getting the same error.

Comment: IF statements are only valid in functions or procedures in MySQL.

Comment: In a regular query you need `IF(...)` but this cannot encapsulate a subselect. You can do it with a `JOIN` though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418514/if-statement-is-not-valid-in-this-position